# allowedMethods Grails

Tags: grails

In grails if you want to map to particular HTTP methods you normally use according to documentation:

```
static allowedMethods = [action1: 'GET', action2: 'POST']
```

but for me it does not always properly map my links.

If I use 'def':

```
def allowedMethods = [action1: 'GET', action2: 'POST']
```

Then the links are mapped correctly but the resource is then not found when using the link.

What?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is here. The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html) clearly states that this property should be `static`, e.g.

```
static allowedMethods = [action1:'POST', action3: 'POST']
```

so if you don't declare it as a static property, I'm not surprised that you run into problems.

If you declare the property as shown above and are sure it's not working, then [report this as a bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS). I expect that the Grails developers will be sceptical about whether this is really a bug in their code, so I strongly recommend including in your report a sample application or unit test that demonstrates the problem.